# Apache POI shows exception if file contains images

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use Apache POI to read .doc file. The code end up with an exception if the .doc file contains images. Files without images get read successfully and gives output.

My code is as follows.

```
File file = null;
WordExtractor extractor = null ;
String res="";
try 
{
    file = new File("E:\\MCA\\S5\\Mini Project\\trial.doc");
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
    HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
    extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
    String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
    for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++)
    {
    fileData[i]=fileData[i].trim();
    out.println(fileData[i]);            
    }
 }

catch(Exception exep)
{
    out.println(exep.getMessage());
}
```

And the exception is triggered at

```
HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
```

Exception:

```
  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /word_read.jsp at line 23

20: {
21:     file = new File("E:\\MCA\\S5\\Mini Project\\trial.doc");
22:     FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
23:     HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
24:     extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
25:     String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
26:     for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++)


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: filesystem
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:906)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:835)
    org.apache.jsp.word_005fread_jsp._jspService(word_005fread_jsp.java:121)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: filesystem
    org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:216)
    org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:157)
    org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:145)
    org.apache.jsp.word_005fread_jsp._jspService(word_005fread_jsp.java:91)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: Which of the POI jar files did you include? And at what versions? This error points to mismatched versions.

Comment: @Thilo I used poi-scratchpad-3.6.jar

Comment: As [clearly detailed in the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C), mixing jars from different POI version *is not* supported. Fix your build to only use jars from the same version